# What is trace of matrix $I+A+A^2$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given that the eigen values of matrix $A_{5\times 5}$ are $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, \alpha^4$ such that $\alpha=e^{i{2\pi}/3}$

then the trace of matrix $I+A+A^2$ is

a) $\ 0\quad$ b) $\ 3\quad$ c)  $\ 5\quad$ d) $\ 15\quad$

**My try:**

Given that

$\alpha=e^{i2\pi/3}\implies \alpha^2=e^{-i2\pi/3}, \ \ \alpha^3=1$ &

$1+\alpha+\alpha^2=0$

Eigen value of $I+A+A^2$ corresponding to $1$ :

$=1+1+1^2$

$=3$

Eigen value of $I+A+A^2$ corresponding to $\alpha$ :

$=1+\alpha+\alpha^2$

$=0$

Eigen value of $I+A+A^2$ corresponding to $\alpha^2$ :

$=1+\alpha^2+\alpha^4$

$=1+\alpha^2+\alpha$

$=0$

Eigen value of $I+A+A^2$ corresponding to $\alpha^3$ :

$=1+\alpha^3+\alpha^6$

$=1+1+1$

$=3$

Eigen value of $I+A+A^2$ corresponding to $\alpha^4$ :

$=1+\alpha^4+\alpha^8$

$=1+\alpha+\alpha^2$

$=0$

Now,the trace of $I+A+A^2$ is

$\text{sum of eigen values}$

$=3+0+0+3+0$

$=6$

But, my answer does not match any option. My teacher  says that option (c) $5$ is correct, but i don't know how. Please suggest me if i am wrong or help me solve this problem.

thanks

Comment: Your teacher is wrong.  You are right.

Comment: Does your teacher use $\alpha=e^{i 2\pi/5}$ instead?

Comment: @Kusma: You are right. My teacher has probably used the same value $\alpha=e^{i2\pi/5}$. Thanks for observing my error

Comment: $1$ and $\alpha ^3$ and $\alpha$ and  $\alpha ^4$ are the same?

Comment: The question as stated is solved correctly by you. However, it does not make sense for the question to write $\alpha^3$ if that happens to be $1$, because then it probably would say $1$, right? That's why it is most likely that the suggestion made by Kusma is the one your teacher intended in which case, the answer is actually one of the four options.

Comment: thank you all for finding my error. My teacher used $\alpha=e^{i2\pi/5}$ as suggested by Kusma. It's my misunderstanding.